# Does "which" indicate that I have just one car?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Does "which" indicate that I have just one car?

> I should sell my car, **which** I use very little.

Does "that" indicate that I have more than one car?

> I should sell my car **that** I use very little.

Comment: Neither indicates unambiguously that you have only one car.   **which** does not imply that you have more than one, but you could.  **that** implies that you do have more than one, since otherwise there would be no need to restrict or limit the statement to refer to the car that is little used, as distinct from some other less-used car or cars.

Comment: @TRomano So, is there any difference between these two sentences?

Comment: I think I was adding a sentence as you were typing your question.

Comment: The comma after car separates the qty. (singular "car") from the condition ("I use very little"), so the first example indicates only one car.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of the two options precisely limits the number of cars you have; I would not suggest using either **which** or **that** in this case, because both words are referring back to the object in the earlier part of the sentence with ambiguous terms.  Of the two options, **which** is closest to the implication that you only have one car, but it does not absolutely rule out the possibility of a second vehicle.

A more precise phrasing might be "I should sell my car, **since** I use it very little."